# how to convert waf build system to exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, waf, nuitka

i use waf(https://waf.io/) as my build system ,
as not ervey my client want install the python , so I want try to convert it (python+waf+wscript) to exe file ,

first I try the pyinstaller ,

```
pyinstaller.exe -F waf
```

it give the error as follows:

```
D:\CX\wafexample\1_basic\15_Task_rule_exe>waf.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "waf", line 162, in 
wafdir = find_lib()
File "waf", line 159, in find_lib
unpack_wafdir(dir, src)
File "waf", line 59, in unpack_wafdir
f = open(src,'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\XIA~1.CHE\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI158042\waf.py'
[11540] Failed to execute script 'waf' due to unhandled exception!
```

then i try the nuitka , it gives as :

```
>waf.cmd configure build
Waf: Run from a folder containing a 'wscript' file (or try -h for the generic options)
```

this means nuitka convert python+waf to  exe , but without the wscript.

can anyone can share how to convert python+waf+wscript to build.exe ?
then i can use

```
 build.exe configure build
```

to build a project ?

maybe someone is not familiar with waf build,
I shorten my question :

how to convert "python a.py b.py"
the b.py calls other python file.
I want convert all features to a standalone exe file .

thanks !

Comment: The build.exe seems to work. The wscript is like a makefile. It's part of the sources, not the build command

Comment: yes, @nerro, you are right , but I wish that the build.exe can contain wscript

Comment: Late reply, but have you looked into Cython (https://cython.org/)? It's a superset of Python that compiles to C, so there's no need for a separate interpreter. I don't know if it supports Waf, but it's worth a shot. (and if you get it to work, I'd be interested to know)

Answer (score 0):

I know *waf*, but not *nuitka*. Just looking through the docs, it seems there's an option to include data files: `--include-data-file`. I think that's the way to go :)

Good luck!